# Saving DataGridView Changes And Showing Identity Value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a WinForms app with a DataGridView control that's bound to a DataTable.  The DataTable gets its data from a SQL Server table containing an identity column.  When the user adds or makes changes to a row and moves to a different row, I want the app to save those changes to the database.  And I want the DataGridView to display the new identity value after a new row is added.

My code is this:

```
        private BindingSource _bs = new BindingSource();

        private void dgv_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgv.IsCurrentRowDirty)
            {
                SaveRowChanges(dgv.CurrentRow);
                RebindDataGridView();  //rebind so new identity value will be shown in grid
            }
        }

        void RebindDataGridView()
        {
            InventoryDatabase db = InventoryDatabase.Instance();
            DataTable dt = db.GetProducts();

            _bs.DataSource = dt;
            dgv.DataSource = _bs;
        }

        public void SaveRowChanges(DataGridViewRow row)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.InventoryDBConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new("Reporting.usp_InsertUpdateProduct", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", row.Cells["txtProductID"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", row.Cells["txtProductName"].Value.ToString());                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", (bool)row.Cells["chkIsActive"].Value);

                SqlParameter prm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductKey", SqlDbType.Int);
                prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that after saving the changes (via SaveRowChanges()), the RebindDataGridView()
method refreshes the whole DataTable - thus causing the dgv_RowValidating() event to fire again and again.  That results in a stack overflow exception.

I've tried moving this code to different DataGridView events like RowValidated() and RowLeave() but those result in the same stack overflow exception.

Is there a different event I should be using?  Or some way to stop the endless loop?  Or a way to display the new identity value in the DataGridView without rebinding?